# Showing progress image between httpGet and response in Android

Tags: java, android, httprequest, httpresponse, http-get

I use the code below to get an XML file from a web service :

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
         String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet HttpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(HttpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity,"UTF-8");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }
```

It takes about 3-4 seconds for the web service to response to the request.
I want to display an image in this time between request and response.

What would be the best way to do so?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use an AsyncTask..and show the progress dialog in preExcecute method and dismiss it in onPostExcecute method

Comment: [check out this example](http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/06/basic-asynctask-with-progress-bar.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask`

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

         // Show image Here
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet HttpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(HttpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity,"UTF-8");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return null;
        }





        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        /Handle Result From server
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
```

Comment: thank you, I faced some difficulties about implementing this code, but finally I managed to use it.